# How do you sign into the Game Center in Pewdiepies tuber simulator

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

I recently had a glitch with the game so I had to delete it. When I got it back, it made me start all over and I can't sign into my old account that was on my Game Center. Is it possible to log in to my old account or do I have to start over?

Answer (score 0):

If you're logged into Game Center it should connect by itself. Try the "Link Account" button in the "Social" tab if it doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work.